# Search and count according to a specific pattern

Tags: r

I have a big data.frame. I have to count how many times a word ending with _xxsgt occurs, column by column.

```
  Col1             Col2  
  a               54_xxsgt   
  123_xxsgt       e     
  d               f  
  429_s_xxsgt     g
```

Desired output:

Col1: 2  (123_xxsgt and 429_s_xxsgt occur)
Col2: 1  (54_xxsgt occur)
....

Comment: A [Reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) would be very helpful for us to help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> DF <- read.table(text=" Col1             Col2  
    a               54_xxsgt   
    123_xxsgt       e     
    d               f  
    429_s_xxsgt     g ", header=T)
> 
> apply(DF, 2, function(x) sum(grepl('_xxsgt', x)))
Col1 Col2 
   2    1
```

Comment: Hi Jiber, sorry for the late answer. I followed you suggestion that was ok for me. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
# First, a reproducible example)
set.seed(42)
dd <- sample(letters[1:20], 100, replace = TRUE)
ix <- as.character(sample(c("", "_xxsgt"), 100, replace = TRUE))
dd <- paste(dd, ix, sep="")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(dd, ncol=10))

# solution
sapply(df, function(x) length(grep("_xxsgt", x)))
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 
 6   7   6   9   4   5   4   5   6   4
```